# Subtract 1 from column number on statusbar in insert mode

Tags: statusline

In insert mode, using beam-cursor, the column number is, at least for me, not intuitive. Having for example the text:

```
abcde
```

and using `%v` on `statusline`.

If cursor is before `a` it say `1`, after `e` it say `6` etc. Perhaps only me being difficult, and at least picky, but how to show one less on status bar in Vim? I would like it to show length of line / string.

Before `a` = `0`, after `e` = `5` etc. In normal mode, with block-cursor, the column number is fine.

Comment: There are 2 difficult problems in computer science: 1) cache invalidation, 2) naming things and 3) off by 1 errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve it is to use a custom function for status line:

```
fun! ImColnr()
    return printf("%d", mode() == "i" ? col(".") - 1 : col("."))
endfun

set statusline=%{ImColnr()}
```

In my usage I have:

```
fun! ImColnr()
    return printf(",%04d", mode() == "i" ? col(".") - 1 : col("."))
endfun
```

as I like fixed with with leading zeroes. My `statusline`, (somewhat bloated), in full is:

```
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w[%L][%{&ff}]%{(&fenc!=''?&fenc:&enc)}%y[%p%%][%04l%{ImColnr()}]\ \ \ F[%2n]:\ %t
```